# Gutenberg - is it ok to load dependencies multiple times?

Tags: plugin-development, javascript, block-editor

Gutenberg comes with its own dependencies, lets say React and React DOM...

If I'm building a plugin, should I add the same dependencies for it? Wouldn't that mean that it loads React twice and it just increases the file size.

Answer (score 1):

No, you should not add the same dependencies. Use dependencies that WordPress core already has. Gutenberg is already loading these, adding your own would lead to complication and most cases some functionality will not work.